# How to enable bootstrap in Asp.net core 2.0.9 web application

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, asp.net-core, .net-core, asp.net-core-2.0

I have created Empty asp.net web application, now I have to add/enable bootstrap support for this application how can I do it.

Project version:

```
<ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.All" Version="2.0.9" />
</ItemGroup>
```

Comment: bootstrap comes by default in wwwroot/lib folder in asp.net core 2.0

Comment: It comes under wwwroot/lib folder when we have selected MVC template at the time of creating the project. But I had selected the empty web application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try [Libman](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/client-side/libman/?view=aspnetcore-2.1).

Option1:

Install Visual Studio 2017 version 15.8 and later, then follow [Visual Studio 2017 version 15.8](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/client-side/libman/libman-vs?view=aspnetcore-2.1)

Option2:

Follow steps below:

1. Run `dotnet tool install -g Microsoft.Web.LibraryManager.Cli` from command
2. Navigate to the wwwroot foler
3. Run `libman init`
4. Run `libman install twitter-bootstrap --destination lib/bootstrap` to install the bootstrap to the specific folder like `wwwroot`